# passing command line parameter to mysql query in a like % statement

Tags: mysql, batch-file, select, sql-like

I'm trying to execute the following .bat procedure passing it e.g. the word "toner":

```
@echo off
@echo use tax; select id,date,account,supplier,item,price from booking where ite
m like '%%1%' >tempquery.sql
"c:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.1\\bin\\mysql.exe" <tempquery.sql
```

Somehow I can't get the LIKE '%Toner%' parameter not correctly passed as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

To print a `%` character using `echo`, you have to put it in twice:

```
@echo use tax; select id,date,account,supplier,item,price from booking where ite
m like '%%%1%%' >tempquery.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I believe I got it. Have to use %% :

```
select id,date,account,supplier,item,price from booking where item like '%%%1%%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `concat()` for this:

```
where item like concat('%%', '%1', '%%')
```

Or, skip `like` altogether:

```
where instr(item, '%1') > 0
```